# How to know the status of Self hosted serivce?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created a self hosted service and used httpcfg ssl command to bind my service to a port. My question is is there any way to know the status of the SERVICE - whether it is running or not ?? Eventthough my program is running without any error, it was failed to provide service to the client later i found that i didnt configure(using httpcfg) my port. So, this could be troubling that my program is running but still failed to provide the service. So, is there any way to know(programmatically) that my service is ready to serve??

Thanks in advance

Madhu Mahesh

Comment: Is i t wcf service? Is it hosted as windows service or console application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, but it requires coding. How to achieve this you can read [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2010/05/17/enabling-service-availability-in-wcf-services.aspx)